# Cannot access non Basic permissions from Instagram API even inside sandbox mode

Tags: php, api, authentication, scope, permissions

According to Instagram API documentation [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/):

> While in sandbox, your app has access to all permissions and you can
> generate access tokens with any scope for testing.

But when I try this url :

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=$valid_id&redirect_uri=$valid_redirectURI&response_type=code&scope=basic+likes+comments+relationships
```

and then logging in  successfully, it shows an error as:

> {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message":
> "Invalid scope field(s): likes,comments,relationships"}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram is discontinuing their platform API in favor of using the new Instagram Graph API and currently all scopes outside of the default basic scope have been removed. In their documentation under **Login Permissions (Scopes)** [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/) they currently state:

> Here are the scopes we currently support:
>
> - basic

Even the basic scope will be discontinued soon according to this page:
https://elfsight.com/blog/2018/02/instagram-graph-api-changes/

> **The following will be deprecated in early 2020:**
>
> - Basic – to read a user’s profile info and media.

So the way forward is to use the [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) instead.